# QRect Width and Height in pixels?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, pixel, qpainter

In a PyQt4 Gui, I require the careful placement of multiple QPainter Pixmaps.
When specifying the coordinates and height and width of the new Pixmaps, I require that all units be in pixels.
(Otherwise, my Gui would be ruined on a screen of a different resolution to my own).

When placing the Pixmap, I use DrawPixmap( QRect , QPixmap ) function.
The Pixmaps needed to be placed are in a list of QRects of Tuples of 4 integers, which specify the coordinates of the top-left corner of the Pixmap (in px) and te bottom-right corner of the Pixmap (in px).
eg:
Blocks = [QtCore.QRect(x1, y1, x2, y2), etc].

Sadly, The last two numbers of the tuple are interpreted as width and height when passed to DrawPixmap( QRect, QPixmap), which are in the units (cm).

My Question...
Is there a method to specify a Pixmaps dimensions entirely in pixels?
(Either by passing a pixel width and height, or the two pixel coordinates of the corners of the dimension box).

I Can't find a way in the QPainter or QRect class references.
Thanks!

---

Specs:
Python 2.7
PyQt4
Windows 7 32bit
IDLE

Comment: Pixmaps are always measured in pixels. Pixmap == a map of pixels. Are you sure that you do not have a higher DPI image? Have you considered looking at the QPainter's drawPixmap function that takes both a destination and the source pixels in the pixmap?

Comment: I manipulate the source image to dimensions that must be in pixels. For some reason, all the specification of dimensions beside position are in width and height, or not specified at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `QPainter` class reference, you can find different overloading of the `drawPixmap` method. Reading the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpainter.html#drawPixmap) tells that `QPainter::drawPixamp(QRect, QPixmap)` do exactly what you want. It might be a specific issue with pyqt where the format of the `QRect` is recognized more as a `QRectF`. You can also use the overloaded function that gets the top left coordinates and the width and height of your area like: `QPainter::drawPixamp(x, y, width, height, QPixmap)`

Comment: I have tried both those functions, and as said, the 'width' and 'height' are interpreted as centimetres (Which the doc states), not pixels. I can only pass it pixels, due to resolution issues.

Comment: Wait.... now I'm not so sure...
How did I ever concieve that height and width were interpreted as cm??
Sure I read it somewhere....